# In the IELTS test, does the word limit include articles and prepositions?

Tags: ielts

> Choose NO MORE THAN ***THREE*** WORDS AND/OR A NUMBER from the passage
> for each answer.
>
> 1. What job did William Hearst do?
> 2. Who helped Hearst design the Castle?
> 3. How much did Hearst spend on art during his lifetime?
> 4. How many times was the Neptune pool rebuilt before Hearst was happy with it?
> 5. What were visitors to the Castle required to do every evening?
> 6. ***Who owns the mansion now?***

Source: *Mindset for IELTS* Level 2, page 12

> 1. (newspaper) publisher
> 2. Julia Morgan
> 3. $3.5 million
> 4. 3 /three
> 5. attend formal dinner(s)
> 6. ***the State of California***

Answer key, page 168

Is the answer to question 6 OK? It has four words.

Comment: Is this an official test by the publisher of the Mindset series (Cambridge University Press), or something locally prepared in your country, for example by your teacher?

Comment: You have a large image of text.  Please use the image as a reference, and retype the words, because images of text are rubbish - they can't be indexed, searched, copied and pasted to a search engine, or read by (some) screenreaders.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: "Is this an official test by the publisher of the Mindset series (Cambridge University Press)" It's [an official Cambridge IELTS course](https://www.cambridge.org/us/cambridgeenglish/catalog/cambridge-english-exams-ielts/mindset-ielts/mindset-ielts-level-2-official-cambridge-ielts-course-students-book-testbank-and-online-modules?isbn=9781316640159&&format=DO).

Comment: @Mori Yes, they've made a basic mistake in the book. All words count as words!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the State of California" is four words.  But you can give the same meaning (in context) by the answer "California" or "California State"